# Percentile in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have many records in excel ordered by time and I need to find an automatic way to find the percentile by another value (speed) for each hour

I set each interval by concatenating day and hour (column "N")
Then I order the records by Interval ("N") then speed ("E")

Now I have to find for each interval the 75 percentile value

[image]

Comment: Without more information, such as how your data looks or what calculation you need to use, how can we help?

Comment: Added image with the last step

Comment: In my opinion the problem is that those intervals contains a different number of records, so I am not able to set the matrix limits for PERCENTILE functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `PERCENTILE` with an array formula defining which values to calculate based on category.

**Picture of ranges**

[image]

**Formula** in cell `D3` is an array formula copied down.  It ensure that the percentile is taken based on category `A` which is dates.  This is an array formula entered with <kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER</kbd>

```
=PERCENTILE(IF($B$3:$B$12=B3,$C$3:$C$12), 0.75)
```

Note also that `PERCENTILE` is technically obsolete and Excel wants you to use `PERCENTILE.EXC` or `PERCENTILE.INC` for the exclusive and inclusive versions.  Believe `INC` is the default that `PERCENTILE` uses.

You get the same answer for each row since it is category based.  You could make a list of unique values somewhere else to only get one value per category.

Comment: I am not able to set the "if" function

Comment: The "if" condition is ok (I had not understad the array formula detail!). Is it possible to set more than one "if" conditions? (2 in my case)

Comment: Sure.  Use `AND(condition1, condition2, etc.)` to get all of your conditions.  There is also an `OR` function, and those can be combined to get all the logic you want.

Comment: The formula (PERCENTILE(IF($B$3:$B$12=B3,$C$3:$C$12), 0.75)) works, but I am not able to understand because it works in your way and it does not works if I insert "E3" instead of "B3" (where E3, E4 is the list of the intervals)